# OnClick change the model.firstObject data

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

1. I have a model that shows data in a li tag on the left side.
2. On the right side one of the model.firstObject display
3. When users click on the current li tag, I would like change the right side model.firstObject to show current li data.

What's the best way to handle something like this?

```
<div class="food-menu">
    <ul class="menu-list">
      {{#each model as |menu|}}
        <li class="menu selectable {{if (eq menu model.firstObject) 'active'}}">
          <div class="picture-wrapper">
            <img src="{{menu.picture}}" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="info-box">
            <h2 class="name">{{menu.name}}</h2>
              <p class="light-blue title-company">
                 {{menu.lowfat}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-detail">
    {{#with model.firstObject as |menu|}}
      <div class="menu menu-banner">
        <div class="picture-wrapper">
          <img src="{{menu.picture}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info-box">
          <h2 class="light name">{{menu.name}}</h2>
          <p class="light-blue title-company">
            {{menu.lowfat}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/with}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Is this `(eq menu model.firstObject)` is working for you ?

Comment: Have you considered to use a nested route for this? Thats the classic use case for nested routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce `selectedObject` instead of `model.firstObject` and update it whenever the lhs side `li` is clicked.

To set initial value for `selectedObject` property in controller, use route's `setupController` hook.

```
setupController(controller,model){
    this._super(...arguments);
    controller.set('selectedObject',model.get('firstObject'));
  }
```

Inside controller, have a action to update the `selectedObject`.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',  
  selectedObject: undefined,
  actions:{
    updateSelectedObject(item){
      this.set('selectedObject',item);
    }
  }
});
```

and in hbs, you need to call `updateSelectedObject` method upon clicking the `li` tag.

```
<div class="food-menu">
    <ul class="menu-list">
      {{#each model as |menu|}}
        <li class="menu selectable {{if (eq menu selectedObject) 'active'}}" {{action 'updateSelectedObject' menu}}>
          <div class="picture-wrapper">
            <img src="{{menu.picture}}" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="info-box">
            <h2 class="name">{{menu.name}}</h2>
              <p class="light-blue title-company">
                 {{menu.lowfat}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-detail">
    {{#with selectedObject as |menu|}}
      <div class="menu menu-banner">
        <div class="picture-wrapper">
          <img src="{{menu.picture}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info-box">
          <h2 class="light name">{{menu.name}}</h2>
          <p class="light-blue title-company">
            {{menu.lowfat}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/with}}
  </div>
```

Comment: As an improvement I suggest using a get/set computed property instead of overriding `setupController`.

Comment: 1.Where should I add the setupController, in the menu controller?

Comment: 2. What arguments should I have for the this._super(...arguments);

Comment: create sample [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/0ab7f13467e582801f126ac6640708f4). i will try incorporate lux and locks comment and update my answer..until then play with this twiddle. setupController hook is for route file may be `routes/application.js`. and you dont need to pass anything. `this._super(...arguments)` this means it will call super method with controller and model as arguments..in super method they will set model properties to controller..that's default behavior because of this we are able to access `model` properties in hbs.

Comment: `controller.set('selectedObject',model.get('firstObject'));` -this will take care.. updated code in answer

Comment: Great working! Learned something new. Feels good :) Thanks Kumkanillam.